# URLEncodedUtils.format() issue in android

Tags: android, urlencode

I discovered that URLEncodedUtils.format() encodes spaces as "+" but not %20
When i pass in parameter NameValuePairs consisting of value with space it encodes spaces as + signs. 
I passed a "time" key with "2011-05-08 21:36:39" value and 
URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"); 
returns 
&time=2011-05-08+21%3A36%3A39& 
where as u can c the space replaced with "+" instead of %20
Why is that? Didn't expect it. Thought space could be encoded exclusively as %20 but not the +...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/paste from http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

`URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a + sign`.

Comment: i thought spaces could be replaced exclusively by %20 sequence thats why i posted an issue. It wasn't a question about could URL contain spaces or not (coz i know it couldn't) it was about weird (as 4 me) encoding.